# How to define the folium colormap position

Tags: python, folium

I have defined a colormap in my folium Map (word_map)

```
color_scale = LinearColormap(['yellow','red'],vmin = min, vmax = max)
colormap =  self.color_scale.to_step(len(countries))
world_map.add_child(colormap)
```

By defaut the colormap is horizontal and located on the top of my map. 
I would like to have a vertical colormap located on the left or on the right of my map.
How can I proceed ?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Were you able to find out how to position colormap.

Comment: @ManmeetSingh unfortunately I have found no solution :(